# UnitOfWork w/ TransactionScope no changes in database but a passing unitTest

Tags: c#, unit-of-work, transactionscope

When trying to insert an entity into a database using a unitOfWork with an transactionScope. I will actually get an expected results back of which user I added (int expectedUserid = uowFactory.Create().AddBasicUser(user);).  But after the UnitOfWork & transactionScope are disposed I don't see any changes in the database. This make me believe I have implemented the transactionScope incorrectly in the UnitOfWork.

I also noticed that when running (debugging) the following unitTest and have a breakPoint on the following line : 60, I am not able to query the database table of 'BasicUser' via MSSQL mngmnt studio (Blocked, JustSaying : Executing query...).

[Said UnitTest (Image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3aRh.png)

The UnitTest itself passes.

**Question:** Why does it seem the UnitOfWork works as intended, but do I not see any changes in the database? And how it comes that the Db is blocked while the transactionScope/UnitOfWork is already disposed.

Thanks a lot!

Refrence Code:

**IUnitOfWorkFactory**

```
namespace DomainServices
{
    public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
    {
        IUnitOfWork Create();
    }
}
```

**UnitOfWorkFactory**

```
using System;
using DomainServices;
using System.Transactions;
namespace DataAccess
{
    public class UnitOfWorkFactory
    {
        private readonly IsolationLevel _isolationLevel;
        private readonly Func<IsolationLevel, IUnitOfWork> CreateUnitOfWork;

        public UnitOfWorkFactory(Func<IsolationLevel, IUnitOfWork> createUnitOfWork, IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
        {
            _isolationLevel = isolationLevel;
            CreateUnitOfWork = createUnitOfWork;
        }

        public IUnitOfWork Create()
        {
            return CreateUnitOfWork.Invoke(_isolationLevel);
        }
    }
}
```

**IUnitOfWork**

```
using System;

namespace DomainServices
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        IUserRepository UserRepository { get; }
        void Dispose();
        void Commit();
    }
}
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
using DataAccess.Repository;
using DomainServices;
using System.Transactions;

namespace DataAccess
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly DatabaseConnection _dbConnection;
        private readonly TransactionScope _transactionScope;
        private bool isDisposed;

        public IUserRepository _userRepository;
        public IUserRepository UserRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._userRepository == null)
                {
                    this._userRepository = new UserRepository(this._dbConnection, this._transactionScope);
                }

                return this._userRepository;
            }
        }

        public UnitOfWork(DatabaseConnection dbConnection, IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
        {
            this.isDisposed = false;
            this._dbConnection = dbConnection;
            this._transactionScope = new TransactionScope(
                TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                new TransactionOptions
                {
                    IsolationLevel = isolationLevel,
                    Timeout = TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout
                });
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            this._transactionScope.Complete();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
        }

        protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.isDisposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    this._transactionScope.Dispose();
                }

                this.isDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**IUserRepository**

```
using Domain;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DomainServices
{
    public interface IUserRepository
    {
        int AddBasicUser(BasicUser basicUser);
        IEnumerable<BasicUser> GetAllBasicUsers();
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Domain;
using DomainServices;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Transactions;

namespace DataAccess.Repository
{
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        private readonly DatabaseConnection _dbConnection;
        private readonly TransactionScope _transaction;
        public UserRepository(DatabaseConnection dbConnection, TransactionScope transaction)
        {
            this._dbConnection = dbConnection;
            this._transaction = transaction;
        }

        public int AddBasicUser(BasicUser basicUser)
        {
            string QueryString = "INSERT INTO BasicUser (Username, RegisterDate) OUTPUT Inserted.Id VALUES (@username, @registerDate);";

            TODO MarWolt: Use a Maybe instead of magic values.
            int basicUserId = -1;

            //using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_dbConnection.ConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryString, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", basicUser.UserName.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RegisterDate", basicUser.RegisterDate);
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        basicUserId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]);
                    }
                }

                scope.Complete();

            }

            return basicUserId;
        }

        public IEnumerable<BasicUser> GetAllBasicUsers()
        {
            var QueryString = "SELECT Id, Username, LastLogin, RegisterDate FROM BasicUser;";
            var result = new List<BasicUser>();
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_dbConnection.ConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryString, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                        result.Add(CreateBasicUserFromReader(reader));
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        private BasicUser CreateBasicUserFromReader(SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            return new BasicUser(
                id: Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]),
                userName: new UserName(Convert.ToString(reader["Username"])),
                lastLogin: DateTime.Now,  //Convert.ToDateTime(reader["LastLogin"]), //TODO MarWolt This...
                registerDate: Convert.ToDateTime(reader["RegisterDate"]),
                rideTokens: new List<RideToken>()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**UnitTestProject**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Transactions;
using DataAccess;
using DataAccess.Repository;
using Domain;
using DomainServices;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UserRepositoryTests
    {
        private UnitOfWorkFactory uowFactory;
        private DatabaseConnection testDatabaseConnection;

        public UserRepositoryTests()
        {
            testDatabaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection(
                "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDb;User Id=DbUser;Password=DbUserPassword;Integrated Security=false;Connect Timeout=5;");
            uowFactory = new UnitOfWorkFactory((IsolationLevel) => new UnitOfWork(testDatabaseConnection, IsolationLevel), IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        }

        [TestInitialize()]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            //TODO MarWolt: delete everything from the database on a clean way.
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(testDatabaseConnection.ConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Properties.Resources.ClearDbSqlScript, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void AddNewBasicUser()
        {
            var user = new BasicUser(new UserName("UnitTestBasicUserName"), DateTime.UtcNow, new List<RideToken>() { });

            var users = uowFactory.Create().UserRepository.GetAllBasicUsers();
            Assert.AreEqual(0, users.Count());

            using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = uowFactory.Create())
            {
                unitOfWork.UserRepository.AddBasicUser(user);
                unitOfWork.Commit();
            }

            users = uowFactory.Create().UserRepository.GetAllBasicUsers();
            Assert.AreEqual(1, users.Count());

            var recievedUser = users.First();
            Assert.AreEqual(user.UserName.Value, recievedUser.UserName.Value);

            // I'm unable to query the database via mssql server management studio when this breakpoint is active.
            // I would actually expect it already to be done after line 51.
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your insert method `AddBasicUser(BasicUser basicUser)` uses a Datareader.  You should use ExecuteNonQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken the time to fully recreate your question into a git repo: [SafariUOW](https://github.com/metalglove/SafariUOW).
And for me it works just fine.

> Why does it seem the UnitOfWork works as intended, but do i not see any changes in the database?

I assume there is a problem in your database with read or write rights if it doesn't actually "Commit".

> And how it comes that the Db is blocked while the transactionScope/UnitOfWork is already disposed.

Well, Db access should be blocked if the transactionScope or UnitOfWork is disposed. It could be you are creating a Transaction with an incorrect Isolationlevel. 
You could look in the [IsolationLevel msdn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.isolationlevel?view=netframework-4.7.2) what the correct level is for your scope.

Please let me know if this answer is good enough for your question.

Regards,
Mario

Answer (score 0):

Your TransactionScope is not actually wrapping the query code.

The code you have commented out:

```
//using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
```

is how you are supposed to do it along, with the other commented out line:

```
//scope.Complete();
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for looking with me, Sorry that was a mistake. i commented those lines out because of me testing why it didnt work. It actualy still does the same with those lines uncommented.